Como resolver este error en IDE Eclipse "The type org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions is not accessible" en una claseTest de un proyecto Java?
Ayuda! Estoy aprendiendo a hacer pruebas. Ya busque como resolver este error pero no logro solucionarlo, la biblioteca de JUnit 5 si esta agregada en el proyecto, no se que otra configuración debo hacer o si debo descargar otra biblioteca? (es un simple proyecto JAVA no es en Maven)
The type org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions is not accessible


Buenas, Ivania, bienvenida al sitio. Hace tiempo que no uso Eclpse pero ¿seguro que has añadido la librería adecuadamente al proyecto? Siguiendo estos pasos Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries => Add JAR. ¿Aparece listada? En caso afirmativo, ¿has probado el primer quick fix que te ofrece el entorno?
